# International to Domestic Transfer at Oslo Airport

Tags: connecting-flights, star-alliance, sas, osl, austrian-airlines

I've been Googling and watching some videos, but I am still confused, and I have got two questions basically. ONE: Can someone tell me the TRANSFER procedure at Oslo Airport? I'll be flying Austrian from my home town (Sarajevo) to Vienna and from Vienna to Oslo, and then SAS from Oslo to Trondheim. What happens with my boarding pass? Both airlines are Star Alliance, so do you think I'll get all passes on my first flight? If I don't, should I get my Trondheim pass in Oslo? Thank you!

Comment: Are all flights booked on the same ticket?

Comment: @JJJ I haven't booked them yet! I'm still in researching part of my trip.

Comment: @xmorellax even so, if you book something as a package (multiple flights with stopovers) then it should be compatible and it applies as such for EU laws. If you're combining different flights yourself you are responsible for showing up to the next flight.

Comment: @JJJ Yes, I would basically buy it all at once, either through expedia or something like that. Google suggests buying it through Austrian Airlines as well. I'm just wondering about this since I'm coming from a non-Eu country and going to non-EU.

Comment: Norway is non-EU but it is Schengen.

Comment: @Willeke That's true, but my country is non-Schengen (but we can travel to Schengen countries without a visa).

Answer (score 1):

**Update** (Covid-19 Situation, 16 August 2020):

- The answer below does not take into account frequently changing rules regarding the Covid-19 situation, and as such is only valid during non-pandemic situations.
- For information please refer to the authoritative sites (as stackexchange can never be accurate on such rapidly changing aspects):

  - [Norwegian Government](https://www.regjeringen.no/en/topics/koronavirus-covid-19/id2692388/)
  - [Norwegian Institute of Public Health](https://www.fhi.no/en/op/novel-coronavirus-facts-advice/facts-and-general-advice/travel-advice-COVID19/#International-travel)
  - [Avinor Airport Information](https://avinor.no/en/information-in-connection-with-the-coronavirus-covid-19/) --> [Transfer rules](https://avinor.no/en/airport/oslo-airport/plan-your-trip/transfer/domestic-transfer)
  - [Norwegian Directorate of Immigration](https://www.udi.no/en/about-the-corona-situation/visits-holiday-and-leisure-trips/#link-18313)
- Hence: at the present moment, the OP would be quarantined if flying in from Bosnia and Herzegovina through Vienna.

> **Generally**:

- Oslo airport is one of the best organized small and modern airports in Northern Europe.

> **Can someone tell me the transfer procedure at Oslo Airport?**:

- You normally arrive in the East Pier section (boarding gates E2-E15, D1-D11 and F12-F26) of the terminals, and will most likely have to proceed to the West Pier section (boarding gates C1-C9).
- Unless you arrive in gates E14/F14 (extremely unlikely in your case), you can just walk to your new gate in max 15mins.
- No passport control (except arriving in E14/F14), however! in the past two years OSL airport police has quite often decided to send a couple of police officers right to the jet bridge (PBB) to check all disembarking passengers' passports quickly. Depending on where you sit, you might want to calculate an additional 1-20min transfer time.
- You board the your connecting SAS flight.

> **What happens with my boarding pass?**:

- Not much, you either get it in Sarajevo, Vienna or Oslo.
- Make sure you have checked in for all flights (online or in Sarajevo).
- If you manage to get it from an SAS counter, you will only get one boarding pass with all three segments printed on it for that day.
- Make sure you also get a mobile boarding pass on your phone as a backup.

> **Do you think I'll get all passes on my first flight?**:

- Yes
- I forgot if Sarajevo had an SAS counter, but in any case just go to the LX/LX/OS counter in Sarajevo and have them print out all boarding passes.
- If for any strange reason you won't get you boarding passes in Sarajevo, go to the SAS counter in Vienna or Oslo.
- Allow for a 60min minimal transfer time in Vienna and Oslo, unless you have HON Circle or VIP/C status and fly all segments in C/D class.

Comment: Due to COVID-19 restrictions, Schengen arrivals are currently in the non-Schengen sector, so there WILL be passport control

Comment: @Crazydre Good point, and in this case the answer is mostly inadequate because right now people coming from Serbia will be quarantined (https://helsenorge.no/koronavirus/travel-advice and https://www.fhi.no/en/op/novel-coronavirus-facts-advice/facts-and-general-advice/travel-advice-COVID19/#International-travel). I answered the general question without Covid-19 background, because there was no mentioning it nor was there any such tag. I believe we cannot keep up with the rapidly changing measurements of governments on stackexchange.

Comment: @Crazydre Amended the answer to reflect your input in a way that should be valuable for anyone hitting this site while trying to find information on traveling to Norway.

Comment: @jcaron True indeed, addressed accordingly. My apologies for this careless geographical mishap. When you travel constantly and you haven't been in a place for a couple of months you tend to mix them up.

Comment: They won't be *quarantined* i.e. escorted and locked up, but advised to self-isolate for up to 10 days, during which you CAN go out, but must "avoid close contact with others", and those working in Norway can't go to work.

Comment: When connecting to a domestic flight you have to pass customs, and this regardless whether you arrive from Schengen or non Schengen. This because most smaller Norwegian airports do not have customs present (some do not even have on site staff) so the general "customs at the final arrival" as is common in the rest of the Schengen area is not practiced here.